# Question about $\frac {\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, special-functions, gamma-function

If $\psi (z)= \log\Gamma(z+1)$

Prove that : $$\psi(n)+\gamma=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$$

My Proof :
$$\psi (z)= \frac {\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}=-\frac{1}{z+1}-\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+z+1}  $$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{n+z+1} -\gamma  \ $$

at $z=n$
$$ \psi(n)+\gamma = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1} $$
$$ \psi(n)+\gamma =(1-1)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\cdots$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}+\cdots $$

$$\psi(n)+\gamma=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}+\cdots $$

where is the error in my proof ?

Comment: If you don't show your work, it is impossible to find what is wrong, if anything. For what we know, perhaps you simply forgot writing the $1$.

Comment: You use $n$ as an argument of $\psi$ and as an index of summation. You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error:

From 
$\psi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+z+1}\right) -\gamma  $
you set $z = n$
to get
$\psi(n)+\gamma = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$,

You use $n$ both as an argument of $\psi$ and as an index of summation. 
You can't do that.

(added later)

From this,
if you set
$z = m$
where $m$ is a positive integer,
$\psi(m)  +\gamma 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+m+1} )
= \sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{n+1}
= \sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}
$,
since all terms from
$n=m+1$
get cancelled out.

(added even later)

Here is why the cancellation happens:

Suppose $N$ is a large integer.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{N}(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+m+1} )
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{n+m+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=m+1}^{N+m+1} \frac{1}{n}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=m+1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n}\right)
-\left(\sum_{n=m+1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=N+2}^{N+m+1} \frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=N+2}^{N+m+1} \frac{1}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

and the right hand sum
is less than
$\frac{m}{N}$
since there are $m$ terms
each of which is
less than
$\frac1{N}$.

Comment: i do that to obtain $\psi(n)$ , we must substitute by n

Comment: Then you *have* to use a different index of summation.

Comment: after this ,
Will i get the result  ?

Comment: Yes. See my amended and corrected answer.